# What is the name of the algorithm, or area of maths that divides a plane around a number of points.

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I'm writing a little program to explore some irregular grid concepts for a game and I cannot for the life of me remember the algorithm that I want for this. I've googled a whole bunch of descriptions but I can't get the name of it.

Take a plane, select some points on that plane. Now draw lines dividing up the plane into regions or "territories" such that each boundary is equidistant from the nearest points.

[image: Example of the divided area]

If the points were arranged in regular rows and columns you'd get a square grid with a point at the centre of each square. If the rows are staggered you'd get a hex grid. And if they're placed down at seemingly random you'd get an irregular grid with 1 point in each "tile" similar to the image.

What's the name of this?

Comment: See: Voronoi diagrams.

Comment: @vvg Thank you! I knew this site would deliver. 20 minutes of googling for nothing, and you just drop the answer on my head in 30 seconds flat.

Comment: @vvg if you want to submit an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a set of points $p \in P$ in a Euclidean plane, the Voronoi diagram is a tesellation or partitioning of the plane into polygons such that the points $q$ within the polygon are closer to the point $p$ than any other as measured by a distance function.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VoronoiDiagram.html for formal definitions.

For related algorithms, see: Menelaos Karavelas. 2D Segment Delaunay Graphs. In CGAL User and Reference Manual. CGAL Editorial Board, 5.5 edition, 2022. url: https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/packages.html#PkgSegmentDelaunayGraph2

Voronoi diagrams are used in many applications including placement of cellphone towers to maximize coverage (with miminal towers) or placement of shops to maximize customer footfalls (with minimal establishment costs).